# Como plotar graficos e imagens .png numa mesma janela com openGL e SDL

Tags: c, imagem, opengl, sdl

Ja fiz alguma busca, em manuais e tal no google porem gostaria de saber como adaptar meu codigo abaixo para plotar um grafico(linha por exemplo) junto com uma imagem de arquivo .png. Não sei onde estou errando abaixo:

```
#include </usr/include/SDL/SDL.h> //compilar com gcc -o exSDLopengl exSDLopengl.c -lSDL -lGL -lSDL_image
#include </usr/include/GL/gl.h>
#include </usr/include/SDL/SDL_image.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

    const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
    const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;
    const int SCREEN_BPP = 32;

    int tex;

 
    void init(){
        glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(0.0,800,600,1.0,-1.0,1.0);
        glEnable(GL_BLEND);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        
    }
  
    void draw2() {
      
      //init();
      glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); // isto é necessário quando se deseja desenhar SEM texturas
      glColor3f(1,1,0);
      glLineWidth(3);
      glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex2i(0,0);
        glVertex2i(100,100);
      glEnd();
      glColor3f(1,1,1);
    
    
     }
     
     void mostra_imagem() {
     
              SDL_Surface* screen1;
              SDL_Surface* imagemPNG;
              SDL_Rect dest;
              
                            
              
              screen1=SDL_SetVideoMode(800,600,16,SDL_SWSURFACE | SDL_OPENGL);
              
              
              
     
              imagemPNG = IMG_Load("mar.png");
              
              dest.x=10;
              dest.y=10;  
              
              SDL_FillRect(screen1, NULL, 0x3); // Pinta de preto todo o screen
              SDL_BlitSurface(imagemPNG, NULL, screen1, &dest); // mostra imagem do mar
              SDL_UpdateRect(screen1,0,0,0,0); // Atualiza o screen com a imagem blitada
              SDL_Delay(1000);  
        } 
    
    int main(int argc,char** argv){
       
        SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
        //SDL_Surface* screen=SDL_SetVideoMode(800,600,32,SDL_SWSURFACE|SDL_OPENGL);
        
               
         int running=1;
        Uint32 start;
        SDL_Event event;
        //init();
        mostra_imagem();
        draw2();
        
    
        SDL_Quit();
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Quando se ativa o OpenGL temos que passar a imagem para uma textura. Depois é preciso chamar a função SDL_GL_SwapBuffers() para atualizar o ecrã.

```
#include </usr/include/SDL/SDL.h> //compilar com gcc -o exSDLopengl exSDLopengl.c -lSDL -lGL -lSDL_image
#include </usr/include/GL/gl.h>
#include </usr/include/SDL/SDL_image.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;
const int SCREEN_BPP = 32;

int tex;

void init(){
    glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.0,640,480,1.0,-1.0,1.0);
    glViewport(0, 0, 640, 480);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    
}

void draw2() {
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); // isto é necessário quando se deseja desenhar SEM texturas
    glColor3f(1,1,0);
    glLineWidth(3);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex2i(0,0);
    glVertex2i(100,100);
    glEnd();
    glColor3f(1,1,1);
}

void mostra_imagem(SDL_Surface* screen, SDL_Surface* image) {
    GLuint texture = 0;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, image->w, image->h, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image->pixels);
    
    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex2f(image->w, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex2f(image->w, image->h);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex2f(0.0f, image->h);
    glEnd();
}

int main(int argc,char** argv){
    
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    int running=1;
    Uint32 start;
    SDL_Event event;
    SDL_Surface* screen1;
    screen1 = SDL_SetVideoMode(800,600,16,SDL_SWSURFACE | SDL_OPENGL);
    SDL_Surface* imagemPNG;
    imagemPNG = IMG_Load("mar.png");
    if(!imagemPNG) {
        printf("IMG_Load: %s\n", IMG_GetError());
    }

    init();
    mostra_imagem(screen1, imagemPNG);
    draw2();
    SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();

    while ( SDL_WaitEvent(&event) >= 0 ) {
        switch (event.type) {
            case SDL_QUIT: {
                printf("Quit.\n");
                exit(0);
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Grato Augusto. Proximo passo e' usar listas para navegar na memoria para animar imagens e desenhos feitos a partir de primitvas. Abraço